# Strip a newline and add more text to a Go bytes.Buffer

Tags: go, logging, server

I wrote a little timer middleware to append the request duration to the end of the log message returned by the excellent [Gorilla Toolkit](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/)'s [`CombinedLoggingHandler`](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/handlers#CombinedLoggingHandler) from the `handlers` package.

That handler accepts an `io.Writer` and an `http.Handler`, and fills the `Writer` with a newline-terminate string containing the [Apache Combined Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format) log entry for the current server request. I would like to remove the trailing newline and add `" completed in xxx"`, where `xxx` is the amount of time the request took.

The following code works, but I am not sure that I made the best use of the Go `bytes.Buffer` in the way I stripped the newline:

```
func timerHandler(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        var b bytes.Buffer
        hand := handlers.CombinedLoggingHandler(&b, h)

        defer func(start time.Time) {
            prefix := bytes.TrimRight(b.Bytes(), "\n")
            os.Stdout.Write(prefix)
            fmt.Printf(" completed in %v\n", time.Since(start))
        }(time.Now())

        hand.ServeHTTP(res, req)
    })
}
```

Is there a better way to write this in Go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are over-complicating the handler function by introducing the deferred function with the start time closure. Additionally, you are performing 2 writes to accomplish the logging, when one would be better.

So, Why have the "defer"? This code:

> ```
>     var b bytes.Buffer
>     hand := handlers.CombinedLoggingHandler(&b, h)
>
>     defer func(start time.Time) {
>         prefix := bytes.TrimRight(b.Bytes(), "\n")
>         os.Stdout.Write(prefix)
>         fmt.Printf(" completed in %v\n", time.Since(start))
>     }(time.Now())
>
>     hand.ServeHTTP(res, req)
> ```

would be simpler to understand as:

```
    start := time.Now()
    var b bytes.Buffer
    hand := handlers.CombinedLoggingHandler(&b, h)

    hand.ServeHTTP(res, req)

    prefix := bytes.TrimRight(b.Bytes(), "\n")
    os.Stdout.Write(prefix)
    fmt.Printf(" completed in %v\n", time.Since(start))
```

Then, in addition, I would manipulate the bytes to trim and add the completion message, and then output them...., so I would change the last part of the code to be something like:

```
    msg := bytes.TrimRight(b.Bytes(), "\n")
    msg := append(msg, []byte(fmt.Sprintf(" completed in %v\n", time.Since(start)...)
    os.Stdout.Write(msg)
```

That still irks me a bit, because i don't like the `os.Stdout.Write` being a constant value in there.... I would make that a parameter somehow, or a constant of some sort....

```
var logDest io.Writer = os.Stdout
```

Comment: Thanks. I could not find any easy way to "back out" the last newline that `CombinedLoggingHandler` added, so trimming seems the only option.